# Requirement to change app name in google sign in alert

Tags: ios, google-signin

[image]

Can we change highlighted text in this alert, for google authentication? 
actually it's taking target name by default. but our app name is different, So is there any way out to change this for this alert?

Comment: Instead of target name you want to use app name or you want to use any other name??

Comment: Have you tried changing the `Product Name` in the project `Build Settings` or the `Bundle Name` in the project `Info.plist`?

Comment: A/c to my knowledge you are using webview and showing any website. If yes, then you cant handle this bcz it is server side popup.

Comment: @ Karthick Ramesh yes

Comment: @Hodson Your solution worked. Thanks buddy :)

Comment: @Nitesh By which name your application is registered on google console?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If we change the bundle name, It will reflect on the alert title as expected.

[image]