# Customizing the title of google sign in popup

Tags: swift

How would I customize the title from saying "Favourites" ... to something else when clicking on the google sign in button on iOS. I don't want to rename my project so is there an alternative to that?

[image]

Comment: I would imagine it's firmly tied to the name of your app. Otherwise, it would be a security concern where you could spoof another app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448989/requirement-to-change-app-name-in-google-sign-in-alert

I found a post that solves my issue. The problem was that my title was exposing internal code so I had to fix that.

Comment: You can change the Display Name only from the build Settings and you don't need to change the Bundle Identifier of the App . the display name will reflect in this Title of the PopUP .